# Docker Compose, Conda, and non-standard certificates

Tags: docker, curl, conda

I'm having some difficulty figuring out how to run `conda install ...` in a Dockerfile, while referencing a non-standard certificates file. In my Dockerfile, I have:

```
RUN REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/non-standard-certificates.pem conda update -n base conda -y
```

which appears to run fine. But then I have:

`RUN REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/non-standard-certificates.pem CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/non-standard-certificates.pem conda install -n base -c defaults -c conda-forge <list-of-packages>`

which ends in:

```
CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64'
```

Can anyone see what is incorrect here?

**Update:**

I have since figured out that I should probably be using `RUN conda config --set client_ssl_cert ...`, and that the certificate file in question had Windows carriage-returns in it (which I removed with `dos2unix`), but now I'm getting a different error:

```
Step 7/29 : RUN conda update -n base conda -y
 ---> Running in 052e36266aef
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 1074, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 84, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 82, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_update.py", line 20, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'update')
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 265, in install
        should_retry_solve=(_should_retry_unfrozen or repodata_fn != repodata_fns[-1]),
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 117, in solve_for_transaction
        should_retry_solve)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 158, in solve_for_diff
        force_remove, should_retry_solve)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 262, in solve_final_state
        ssc = self._collect_all_metadata(ssc)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/common/io.py", line 88, in decorated
        return f(*args, **kwds)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 415, in _collect_all_metadata
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 1004, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs, self._repodata_fn)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 214, in get_reduced_index
        repodata_fn=repodata_fn)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 97, in query_all
        result = tuple(concat(executor.map(subdir_query, channel_urls)))
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 598, in result_iterator
        yield fs.pop().result()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 435, in result
        return self.__get_result()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 384, in __get_result
        raise self._exception
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 57, in run
        result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 90, in <lambda>
        package_ref_or_match_spec))
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 102, in query
        self.load()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 166, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 240, in _load
        repodata_fn=self.repodata_fn)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 477, in fetch_repodata_remote_request
        timeout=timeout)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
        timeout=timeout
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
        chunked=chunked)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
        self._validate_conn(conn)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
        conn.connect()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
        ssl_context=context)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 338, in ssl_wrap_socket
        context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 439, in load_cert_chain
        self._ctx.use_privatekey_file(keyfile or certfile)
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 990, in use_privatekey_file
        self._raise_passphrase_exception()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/SSL.py", line 967, in _raise_passphrase_exception
        _raise_current_error()
      File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 54, in exception_from_error_queue
        raise exception_type(errors)
    OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('PEM routines', 'get_name', 'no start line'), ('SSL routines', 'SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file', 'PEM lib')]

`$ /opt/conda/bin/conda update -n base conda -y`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/opt/conda
                     PATH=/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin
                          :/bin
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>

     active environment : None
       user config file : /root/.condarc
 populated config files : /root/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.12
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.4.final.0
       virtual packages :
       base environment : /opt/conda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /opt/conda/pkgs
                          /root/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /opt/conda/envs
                          /root/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.12 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.7.4 Linux/3.10.0-1160.6.1.el7.x86_64 debian/10 glibc/2.28
                UID:GID : 0:0
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.

Upload did not complete.
ERROR: Service 'base_image' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c conda update -n base conda -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```